# Angular-Cli set default path for live reload during development of the application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-cli

I am using "ng serve" to run my angular project(Angular 5), --liveReload is currently active that reloads the app whenever a change is saved. I need my application to always reload from the base path not the route that was previously active.

For ex: If I am on "http://localhost:4200/users" and save a change , I want the app to live reload from "http://localhost:4200". Please suggest how can I achieve that?

Comment: It can be done only using lazy loading.

Comment: Why would you want that? This wish honestly sounds like your routing doesn't work properly; in essence: you lack state when reloading the page which mean your user emailing a URL or bookmarking your page will also lack state.

Answer (score 0):

Your page will reload, triggering your components to reload as well.
in your app.component.ts you can set it to route to the root dir on load.
You can use the environments file to distinguish between dev and prod.